# C# Cache Is not showing the original value stored in the Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am trying to store value in the cache and retrieve it back to improve the processing time.  When I got back the cache item, I need to calculate the value.  But the problem is that it is not giving me the original value which I have stored in the cache.  Instead of that, it is giving me the latest value which I have calculated after getting it from the cache.

I used the following to simulate my problem.  I stored "abc123" in the cache first time.  Then I changed it to "def".  But when I get it back, it shows "def" instead of "abc123".  Is it supposed to be like that?  Or is it me who is doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyObj abc = (MyObj)Cache["myCache"];


    if (abc != null)
    {
        Response.Write(abc.MyText);
        Response.End();
        return;
    }        

    Response.Write(abc);        

    abc = new MyObj() { MyText = "abc123" };

    Cache.Insert("myCache", abc, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero);

    abc.MyText = "def";
}

class MyObj
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing the same object (reference) that is in the cache. If you do not want this behavior you need to clone the object before you put it in the cache.

Comment: I thought Cache Objects are independent to the original objects.  Now I know that they are closely coupled together.  I put the .Clone or .Copy calls to my codes and it solves all.  Thanks.